# Script is printing "select" and "unselect" in the editor console:

Tags: select, editor, maya, maya-api, unselect

In Maya, when running a Python script, the script editor is reporting back every time the script select and unselects something. It is messy and I would rather have that happen under the hood. Is there a way for the script editor to not report those commands, and can I have my script turn the option off in the editor before running?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a little odd... do you happen to have echo all commands turned on in the script editor?

The only other thing I can think of is that the script may be explicitly running print statements - do you have access to the source code so you can comment out any print lines?

Edit:
If you wrote it, maybe you could tweak the code to no longer require selection. There are really very few Maya commands that actually require selection - they work with selection, but also allow you to explicitly provide node names... most commands also return node names that you can capture into a variable.

If you are no longer selecting/deselecting things in your script, it shouldn't clutter your script editor output with those prints anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry for my slow reply.

Comment: I dont not have access to the source code inside of Maya, at least in a form I can use or understand.  The statements are reported in the script editor window.  I am trying to post an image example.

Comment: hmm... where did you get the script?  Have you used other scripts from the same author, and if so, do they do this too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am the author of the script.  I believe it to be a Maya issue.  It will report certain actions and you can't turn it off.